# "Stupid Table" plugin: how not to sort the table backwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's a table with data. You only need to sort it from higher to lower value, on the contrary, you do not need to. This table has an ordinal numeric number, after sorting it is necessary to always be from 1 to 5.

1. How to sort only from more to less?
2. How to make a sequential number after sorting to be 1 to 5?

I'm using the [**Stupid Table Plugin**](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin)

```js
$("#simpleTable").stupidtable();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stupidtable/1.1.3/stupidtable.min.js"></script>
<table id="simpleTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sort="int">#</th>
      <th data-sort="int">int</th>
      <th data-sort="float">float</th>
      <th data-sort="string">string</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>banana</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>95</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>coke</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>152.5</td>
      <td>apple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>88.5</td>
      <td>zebra</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>195</td>
      <td>858</td>
      <td>orange</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stupidtable/1.1.3/stupidtable.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Carlos Martins: Stupid Table is the name of the plugin: https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin

Comment: @user1170330 You are right but I understand Carlos, as probably the question was downvoted because it sounded "rude" to someone unaware of that plugin name. (Btw: not the best name for a plugin)

Comment: Apologies for not search for the plugin name.

Comment: I think having to only allow unidirectional sort is a pretty advanced and uncommon feature, something that most table plugins don't support. Your best choice is to fork the code, and then hack it or modify it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Table-Sort-Plugin-jQuery-Stupid-Table.html

There is `desc` option to sort backwards

```html
<th data-sort="int" data-sort-default="desc">int</th>
```

Looks like it is not possible to do this using this lib.
So you can do hack like below, but you will have issue with header icon still.

```js
const sortFn = (a, b) => {
  return parseInt(a, 10) - parseInt(b, 10);
};

const changableDirSortFn = (dir => {
  let changed = false;
  return (a, b) => {
    if (!changed) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dir = 1 - dir;
        changed = false;
      }, 0);
    }
    changed = true;
    return sortFn(a, b) * (dir * 2 - 1);
  };
})(0);

const data = [1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4];

document.querySelector('.sort').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('sorted data using same function:', data.sort(changableDirSortFn));
});
```

```html
<button class="sort">sort hack</button>
```

Comment: how to make the sorting only one way?

Comment: Looks like it is not possible, but you can implement some hack like this above I proposed.